# What do the commands with this '-' sign do?

Tags: linux, git, terminal

I have this command:

```
git checkout -b <name>
```

What does **-b** do in this command? Where can I read about such commands in git and in the terminal in particular?

Comment: The `-` followed by one or more characters are called command line options. They change the behaviour of the command being invoked. The way to find out what each option means for a particular command is to read its manual page or documents. For example: [git checkout doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33754671/1256452) the kind of Q&A you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-b` option specifies a git branch to check out.

For more information, view the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs).

The description of the `-b` option in the git documentation is a little dense:

> ```
> git checkout -b|-B <new_branch> [<start point>]
> ```
>
> Specifying `-b` causes a new branch to be created as if
> `git-branch[1]` were called and then checked out. In this case you can
> use the `--track` or `--no-track` options, which will be passed to git
> branch. As a convenience, `--track` without `-b` implies branch
> creation; see the description of `--track` below.
>
> If `-B` is given, `<new_branch>` is created if it doesn’t exist;
> otherwise, it is reset. This is the transactional equivalent of
>
> ```
> $ git branch -f <branch> [<start point>]
> $ git checkout <branch>
> ```
>
> that is to say, the branch is not reset/created unless "git checkout"
> is successful.

Answer (score 0):

**They are command options or parameters.**

Commands can take many different options as input, and usually (but not always) these options are prefixed by `-` or `--`, followed by a letter or word, and then sometimes followed again by a value for that option.

For `git checkout` the `-b` option allows you to specify a value for branch name.

You can type `git --help` to view high level options or `git checkout -h` to find out about options specific to `checkout` function.  However, Git being a large complex tool, has many many options so suggest to check out the [official documentation online](https://git-scm.com/docs), rather than only the built in help on terminal.

**Getting help for terminal commands in general:** For most commands, you can type `<command> --help` or try `-h` if that didn't work.  To read the long-form manual for a command type `man <command>`.  To search through a list of all available commands try `apropros <search terms>` to find one you want.

**BONUS TIP:** If you are new to Linux terminal in general, and want to learn various commands quickly without having to google a lot, may I suggest installing the `tldr` tool.

`sudo apt install tldr`

Once installed via the above command, you can run `tldr <command name>`.
For example try `tldr tar` and it gives you some nice examples about how to use the tool.